# osm2po missing ways for Romania

Tags: postgresql, osm2po, geofabrik

I've been trying to import all the ways for Romania into my PostgreSQL database using Geofabrik and osm2po.

However, I noticed that some chunks of a county road are missing by using the following query:

```
SELECT id, geom_way FROM ro_2po_4pgr,
(
    SELECT ST_Expand(ST_Extent(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(23.2161769, 45.6347162), 4326)), 0.2) as box
) as bbox
WHERE ro_2po_4pgr.geom_way && bbox.box
```

Which resulted in:
[image]

The missing chunks for road DJ705A that I have found on openstreetmap.org are:

254048490
258364773
661526471
258367634
254112343
778597709
778324715

You can find them by replacing the last param at this url: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/254048490

With the help of a gentleman from Geofabrik (I was thinking that there was the issue) I received the confirmation that these ways do exist, plus he gave me the following command to run for myself:

```
osmium cat -tway romania-latest.osm.pbf -fopl | grep -e w254048490 -e w258364773 -e w661526471 -e w258367634 -e w254112343 -e w778597709 -e w778324715
```

Indeed, these ways do exist in the `.pbf` file, but they are not present in the generated `.sql` file.

I tried increasing the memory, the tile size, even importing `service` and `living_street` highway types.

I tried parsing the data from `.bz2` with the comand:

```
curl -s -L http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/romania-latest.osm.bz2 | bzcat -c | java -Xmx12g -jar osm2po-core-5.3.2-signed.jar prefix=ro cmd=c tileSize=x postp.0.pipeOut=true log.0.to=err postp.0.class=de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgRoutingWriter > ro.sql
```

(here it spits the output straight to an `.sql` file)
... it still did not work.

This is the command that retrieved the maximum amount of ways (**740073**)

```
java -Xmx32g -jar osm2po-core-5.3.2-signed.jar cmd=tjsp prefix=ro tileSize=x http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/romania-latest.osm.pbf postp.0.class=de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgRoutingWriter
```

(whether I used 6GB, 10GB, 12GB or 32GB it did not make any difference)

I could really use some help, since I ran out of options and all of this is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sending an email to `osm2po` a few days ago, sir Carsten gave me the answer:
`.default.wtr.deny.tracktype.grade[4|5] = car|bike` - *line 241 in osm2po.config*

I commented it out and it worked!